# Existence of increasing continuous function that has specific integral value

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous increasing function on $ \left[a, \;b \right]$,  it is obvious that $ f(a)(b-a) < \int_a ^b f(x)dx < f(b)(b-a) $.

On the other hand, I want to show that:

Let $ p, \;q $ be constants ($p < q$), for all $  k $ that satisfies $  p(b-a) < k < q(b-a)$, there exists continuous increasing function $ f $
such that $ f(a) = p, \;f(b) = q,\; \int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx = k$

It seems very natural when I sketch some graphs of f, but I cannot prove this. How can prove or disprove this statement?

Comment: Do you mean strictly increasing function or are you okay also with just $f(x)\geq f(x')$ when $x>x'$?

Comment: strictly increasing function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that a line function $f$ satisfying $f(a)=p$ and $f(b)=q$ is given by

$$  f(x)=x\cdot \frac{q-p}{b-a}+\frac{bp-aq}{b-a}, $$

and its integral on $[a,b]$ is equal to

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx= \frac{b-a}{2}\cdot(p+q). $$

Now there exists $0<\alpha<1$ such that $k=(b-a)\cdot( \alpha q+(1-\alpha p) )$, so using the above computation for the piecewise linear function $g$ such that $g(a)=p$, $g\big(a+(1-\alpha)(b-a)\big)=\frac{k}{b-a}$ and $g(b)=q$, yields that

$$ \int_a^b g(x)dx= \int_a^{a+(1-\alpha)(b-a)} g(x)dx+ \int_{a+(1-\alpha)(b-a)}^b g(x)dx =$$
$$=\frac{(1-\alpha)(b-a)}{2}\cdot(p+\frac{k}{b-a})+\frac{b-a-(1-\alpha)(b-a)}{2}\cdot(q+\frac{k}{b-a})= $$

$$= \frac{b-a}{2}\cdot \big(p(1-\alpha)+q \alpha)+\frac{k}{2}=k $$

Since a piecewise linear function is continuous, and the slope is positive in each sub-interval, this function should work.